# HLSL and DirectX

Tags: windows-mobile, directx, hlsl

For Windows Mobile DirectX: does it support HLSL or is it only for use on desktop DirectX? I tried doing some Google searches however it doesn't seem to give me anything although I am probably not looking hard enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that Windows Mobile DirectX doesn't support any shaders. In the "How to: Convert Desktop Direct3D Applications" ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229668%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) there is the point "remove unsupported functionality", where is stated "Remove pixel and vertex shaders.". Moreover the whole methods, which provide shader functionality seems to be removed.